# MySQL Error when adding several foreign keys of the same type to one table

Tags: mysql

MySQL Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fkUsers6' in the reference table 'users'

Happens when there is more than one foreign key of the same type in the table. Any idea to solve this? I haven't found answers to this case yet ...

Table in which the error occurs:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`opportunities` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `opportunity_belongsTo` INT NULL,
  `opportunity_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_stage` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_product` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_volume` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_dateCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_createdFrom` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_datePlannedClosure` DATE NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_dateChanged` DATETIME NULL,
  `opportunity_changedFrom` INT NULL,
  `opportunity_dateClosed` DATETIME NULL,
  `opportunity_closedFrom` INT NULL,
  `opportunity_dateDeleted` DATETIME NULL,
  `opportunity_deletedFrom` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

Creation of the foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `profiCRM`.`opportunities`
  ADD INDEX `fkAccounts_idx` (`opportunity_belongsTo` ASC),
  ADD INDEX `fkOpportunityStage_idx` (`opportunity_stage` ASC),
  ADD INDEX `fkOpportunityType_idx` (`opportunity_type` ASC),
  ADD INDEX `fkProducts_idx` (`opportunity_product` ASC),
  ADD INDEX `fkUsers_idx` (`opportunity_createdFrom` ASC, `opportunity_changedFrom` ASC, `opportunity_closedFrom` ASC, `opportunity_deletedFrom` ASC),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fkAccounts6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_belongsTo`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`accounts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fkOpportunityStage6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_stage`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`opportunityStage` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fkOpportunityType6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_type`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`opportunityTypes` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fkProducts6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_product`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`products` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fkUsers6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_createdFrom` , `opportunity_changedFrom` , `opportunity_closedFrom` , `opportunity_deletedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID` , `ID` , `ID` , `ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Table of which the foreign key is from:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`users` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_belongsTo` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_dateOfBirth` DATE NOT NULL,
  `user_adress1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_adress2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_department` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_zipcode` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_state` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_country` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_telephoneFixed` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_telephoneMobile` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_rightViewData` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_rightCreateData` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightCreateUser` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightCreateAttribute` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightCreateList` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightEditData` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightEditUser` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightEditAttribute` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightEditList` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightDeleteData` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightDeleteUser` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightDeleteAttribute` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightDeleteList` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_dateCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `user_createdFrom` INT NULL,
  `user_dateChanged` DATETIME NULL,
  `user_changedFrom` INT NULL,
  `user_dateDeleted` DATETIME NULL,
  `user_deletedFrom` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

> Here the solution: (I had to define an own foreign key for every
>   single list item, the possibility to select several items for one key
>   in the MySQL Workbench is not such purposeful)

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Wed Oct 25 14:20:25 2017
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema profiCRM
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema profiCRM
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
SHOW WARNINGS;
USE `profiCRM` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`countries`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`countries` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `countryName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`users` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_belongsTo` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_dateOfBirth` DATE NOT NULL,
  `user_adress1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_adress2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_department` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_zipcode` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_state` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_country` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_telephoneFixed` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_telephoneMobile` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_rightViewData` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_rightCreateData` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightCreateUser` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightCreateAttribute` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightCreateList` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightEditData` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightEditUser` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightEditAttribute` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightEditList` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightDeleteData` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightDeleteUser` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightDeleteAttribute` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_rightDeleteList` TINYINT NULL,
  `user_dateCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `user_createdFrom` INT NULL,
  `user_dateChanged` DATETIME NULL,
  `user_changedFrom` INT NULL,
  `user_dateDeleted` DATETIME NULL,
  `user_deletedFrom` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fkCountries_idx` (`user_country` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsers_idx` (`user_rightViewData` ASC),
  INDEX `fkCorporateAccounts_idx` (`user_belongsTo` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToCreatedFrom_idx` (`user_createdFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToChangedFrom_idx` (`user_changedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToDeletedFrom_idx` (`user_deletedFrom` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkCountries2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_country`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`countries` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToRightViewData2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_rightViewData`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkCorporateAccounts2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_belongsTo`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`corporateAccounts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToCreatedFrom2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_createdFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToChangedFrom2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_changedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToDeletedFrom2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_deletedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`corporateAccounts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`corporateAccounts` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `corporateAccount_name1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_name2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `corporateAccount_adress1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_adress2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `corporateAccount_department` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `corporateAccount_zipcode` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_state` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `corporateAccount_country` INT NOT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_parentTo` INT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_childOf` INT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_dateCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_dateChanged` DATETIME NULL,
  `corporateAccount_changedFrom` INT NULL,
  `corporateAccount_dateDeleted` DATETIME NULL,
  `corporateAccount_deletedFrom` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fkCountries_idx` (`corporateAccount_country` ASC),
  INDEX `fkCorporateAccounts_idx` (`corporateAccount_parentTo` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsers_idx` (`corporateAccount_changedFrom` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersDeletedFrom_idx` (`corporateAccount_deletedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkCorporateAccountsToChildOf1_idx` (`corporateAccount_childOf` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkCountries1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`corporateAccount_country`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`countries` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkCorporateAccountsToParentTo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`corporateAccount_parentTo`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`corporateAccounts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToChangedFrom1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`corporateAccount_changedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToDeletedFrom1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`corporateAccount_deletedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkCorporateAccountsToChildOf1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`corporateAccount_childOf`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`corporateAccounts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`accountTypes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`accountTypes` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountType_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`competition`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`competition` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `competition_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`opportunityStage`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`opportunityStage` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `opportunityStage_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`opportunityTypes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`opportunityTypes` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `opportunityType_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`products`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`products` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`opportunities`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`opportunities` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `opportunity_belongsTo` INT NULL,
  `opportunity_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_stage` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_product` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_volume` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_dateCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_createdFrom` INT NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_datePlannedClosure` DATE NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_dateChanged` DATETIME NULL,
  `opportunity_changedFrom` INT NULL,
  `opportunity_dateClosed` DATETIME NULL,
  `opportunity_closedFrom` INT NULL,
  `opportunity_dateDeleted` DATETIME NULL,
  `opportunity_deletedFrom` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fkAccounts_idx` (`opportunity_belongsTo` ASC),
  INDEX `fkOpportunityStage_idx` (`opportunity_stage` ASC),
  INDEX `fkOpportunityType_idx` (`opportunity_type` ASC),
  INDEX `fkProducts_idx` (`opportunity_product` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsers_idx` (`opportunity_createdFrom` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToChangedFrom6_idx` (`opportunity_changedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToClosedFrom6_idx` (`opportunity_closedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToDeletedFrom6_idx` (`opportunity_deletedFrom` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkAccounts6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_belongsTo`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`accounts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkOpportunityStage6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_stage`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`opportunityStage` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkOpportunityType6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_type`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`opportunityTypes` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkProducts6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_product`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`products` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToCreatedFrom6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_createdFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToChangedFrom6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_changedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToClosedFrom6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_closedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToDeletedFrom6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`opportunity_deletedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`accounts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`accounts` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_belongsTo` INT NOT NULL,
  `account_kindOf` INT NOT NULL,
  `account_name1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `account_name2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_adress1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `account_adress2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_zipcode` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `account_city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `account_state` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_country` INT NOT NULL,
  `account_email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_telephoneFixed` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_telephoneMobile` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_fax` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_internet` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_childOf` INT NULL,
  `account_parentTo` INT NULL,
  `account_turnover` INT NULL,
  `account_numberEmployees` INT NULL,
  `account_numberSubsidaries` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_generalInfo` VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
  `account_competition` INT NULL,
  `account_opportunities` INT NULL,
  `account_dateCreated` DATETIME NULL,
  `account_createdFrom` INT NULL,
  `account_dateChanged` DATETIME NULL,
  `account_changedFrom` INT NULL,
  `account_dateDeleted` DATETIME NULL,
  `account_deletedFrom` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fkUsers_idx` (`account_belongsTo` ASC),
  INDEX `fkCountries_idx` (`account_country` ASC),
  INDEX `fkAccounts_idx` (`account_childOf` ASC),
  INDEX `fkAccountTypes_idx` (`account_kindOf` ASC),
  INDEX `fkCompetition_idx` (`account_competition` ASC),
  INDEX `fkOpportunities_idx` (`account_opportunities` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC),
  INDEX `FKUsersToCreatedFrom3_idx` (`account_createdFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToChangedFrom3_idx` (`account_changedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToDeletedFrom3_idx` (`account_deletedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkAccountsToParentTo3_idx` (`account_parentTo` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToBelongsTo3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_belongsTo`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkCountries3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_country`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`countries` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkAccountsToChildOf3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_childOf`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`accounts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkAccountTypes3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_kindOf`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`accountTypes` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkCompetition3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_competition`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`competition` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkOpportunities3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_opportunities`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`opportunities` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToCreatedFrom3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_createdFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToChangedFrom3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_changedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToDeletedFrom3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_deletedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkAccountsToParentTo3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_parentTo`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`accounts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`formOfAdress`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`formOfAdress` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `formOfAdress_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`contacts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`contacts` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_belongsTo` INT NOT NULL,
  `contact_formOfAdress` INT NOT NULL,
  `contact_title` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `contact_firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `contact_lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `contact_function` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `contact_department` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `contact_telephoneFixed` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `contact_telephoneMobile` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `contact_email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `contact_fax` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `contact_dateOfBirth` DATE NULL,
  `contact_childOf` INT NULL,
  `contact_parentTo` INT NULL,
  `contact_generalInfo` VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
  `contact_dateCreated` DATETIME NULL,
  `contact_createdFrom` INT NULL,
  `contact_dateChanged` DATETIME NULL,
  `contact_changedFrom` INT NULL,
  `contact_dateDeleted` DATETIME NULL,
  `contact_deletedFrom` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fkAccounts_idx` (`contact_belongsTo` ASC),
  INDEX `fkFormOfAdress_idx` (`contact_formOfAdress` ASC),
  INDEX `fkContacts_idx` (`contact_childOf` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsers_idx` (`contact_createdFrom` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fkContactsToParentTo4_idx` (`contact_parentTo` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToChangedFrom4_idx` (`contact_changedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsersToDeletedFrom4_idx` (`contact_deletedFrom` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkAccounts4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_belongsTo`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`accounts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkFormOfAdress4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_formOfAdress`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`formOfAdress` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkContactsToChildOf4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_childOf`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`contacts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToCreatedFrom4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_createdFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkContactsToParentTo4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_parentTo`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`contacts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToChangedFrom4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_changedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToDeletedFrom4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_deletedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`activityType`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`activityType` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activityType_description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profiCRM`.`activities`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiCRM`.`activities` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activity_belongsToContact` INT NOT NULL,
  `activity_belongsToUser` INT NULL,
  `activity_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `activity_dateStart` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `activity_dateEnde` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `activity_childOf` INT NULL,
  `activity_goal` VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
  `activity_result` VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
  `activity_todo` VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
  `activity_todoTimeframe` DATE NULL,
  `activity_dateCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `activity_createdFrom` INT NOT NULL,
  `activity_dateChanged` DATETIME NULL,
  `activity_changedFrom` INT NULL,
  `activity_dateClosed` DATETIME NULL,
  `activity_closedFrom` INT NULL,
  `activity_dateDeleted` DATETIME NULL,
  `activity_deletedFrom` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fkActivityTypes_idx` (`activity_type` ASC),
  INDEX `fkContacts_idx` (`activity_belongsToContact` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUsers_idx` (`activity_belongsToUser` ASC),
  INDEX `fkActivities_idx` (`activity_childOf` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUserToCreatedFrom5_idx` (`activity_createdFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUserToChangedFrom5_idx` (`activity_changedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUserToClosedFrom5_idx` (`activity_closedFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fkUserToDeletedFrom5_idx` (`activity_deletedFrom` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkActivityTypes5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_type`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`activityType` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkContacts5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_belongsToContact`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`contacts` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUsersToBelongsToUser5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_belongsToUser`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkActivities5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_childOf`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`activities` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUserToCreatedFrom5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_createdFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUserToChangedFrom5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_changedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUserToClosedFrom5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_closedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkUserToDeletedFrom5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_deletedFrom`)
    REFERENCES `profiCRM`.`users` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: `opportunity_created From` INT NOT NULL, was not causing the error, I've made the correction in all places ...

Comment: Hi. Please google your error message, you are not the first person to get it. This is a faq. Also please read [ask] & other links at [help], also very importantly [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your friendly comment. I've already searched a lot and I've also successfully added all the indexes now - but haven't found the "faq-case" of more than one foreign key of the same type in one table. Most common solution is mismatching of data types ... but they are the same here. Error is still the same also after adding all the indexes in all the tables ... it's the only case where I have this problem ...

Comment: Are INT NULL and INT NOT NULL different data types causing a mismatching in this case?

Comment: Did you google the error message sans your application-specific table/column/constraint names? (A zillion questions & answers.) Did you read every mention of "FK" in the manual? (No. That is why there is a F in 'RTFM'.) Google 'more foreign key error info mysql'? Google many clear, concise, specific (but not overly) variants of your question/problem/desiderata? (Well, here that's the error message, per above.) Anyway: the error message tells you it can't find an index `users (ID , ID , ID , ID)`. A FK must be to a *declared* UNIQUE NOT NULL. As the documentation on FKs tells you.

Comment: `Are INT NULL and INT NOT NULL different data types` NO, they are both `INT data types` (exactly the same data type)  in the first instance NULLs are allowed, in the second instance NULLs are not permitted.

Comment: INT NULL & INT NOT NULL are not "different data types", because they are not data types, because INT is a data type & NOT NULL is a constraint, but some columns are sufficiently differently declared to impede a FK-PK match. Read the official documentation re FK declaration. So, learn the relevant notions/terms & how they matter.

Comment: PS Part of composing a [mcve] would be, re minimal, to only declare the one FK with the error. (Maybe with only the tables in the error, with only the columns in the error.) Then you would see "multiple FKs" is irrelevant. (I don't know why you thought it was. Or--do you think that fkUsers6 is "multiple" FKs? No, it's one composite FK, with 4 columns.) The more you take [so] & [se] documention & Q&A, comments & the manual seriously and precisely the more you'll both help yourself & get good answer posts. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Progman had the solution and I posted the correct code directly below my question to help other users ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a foreign key from the four columns `opportunities(opportunity_createdFrom, opportunity_changedFrom, opportunity_closedFrom, opportunity_deletedFrom)` to the (non-existing) index `users (ID , ID , ID , ID)` doesn't make any sense. In fact, you can't create an index with duplicate columns like you try (unintentionally).

What you really want to do is to define separated foreign keys for the four columns of the `opportunities` table to the `id` column in the `users` table.

Comment: You made my day! Yes, I had to define own foreign keys for each table item even when they are from the same table and with same ID. I was a bit seduced by the mySQL-Workbench because I had the possibility to select several list items for the same foreign key. I post the solution directly in my question to help other people with the same problem. And thank you very much for your kindly formulated answer!